# How do I access global variables that are set inside an event listener?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, events, variables, google-maps-api-3

I am working with Google maps api V3.  I need to get the values of the `getSouthWest` & `getNorthEast` bounds of my map.  To do this the 'bounds_changed' event needs to be fired in order to get the new values.  This is all good, however, I need to access these values from outside the event and passed to a server side function (more specifically, I don't want to call my server side function every time the map bounds are changed).

My code is:

```
//Global
var sw, nw, Searchbounds;

function myFunc(){

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
        Searchbounds = map.getBounds();
        sw = Searchbounds.getSouthWest();
        ne = Searchbounds.getNorthEast();

    });

    CallServerSideWebService(sw.lat(), ne.lng(), ne.lat(), ne.lng());
}
```

When executing this code I get the error message `sw is undefined`.

If anyone knows how I can get around this issue with the current method; or access the `getBounds()` function without the use of an event, then I would be very grateful!

Comment: Your code doesn't look right - is this actually the code you're using? If not please copy/paste the exact code.

- You define var nw, but use ne.
- You send ne.lng() twice, and never send sw.lng()

Your code should absolutely be throwing an error when you try and call sw.lat() before you've assigned a value to sw - do you initialize these variables elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a timing issue to me, not a scoping issue.

1. Your function fires and adds the handler
2. Then it tries to access sw which is undefined (as it was when it was declared)
3. Then the event might fire and set sw.

I suppose it is possible that the API is changing a single object reference and you are holding on to that, but it seems unlikely. If that IS the case, try storing the lat and lng values instead of nw and sw since they are number primitives.

You must, though, have access to map outside of the event. It looks as simple as:

```
function myFunc() {
  var searchBounds = map.getBounds();
  var sw = searchBounds.getSouthWest();
  var ne = searchBounds.getNorthEast();

  CallServerSideWebService(sw.lat(), ne.lng(), ne.lat(), ne.lng());
}
```

Comment: I'd agree with your conclusion but from the comments on my answer, @user547043 insists "The value before the event is a default value" even though that isn't obvious in the sample code. That said, I wouldn't bet against you :)

Comment: Yeah, I read that and to be honest, I have trouble believing it. Can you post something that I can run that will reproduce the issue? I know I can solve it if I can see it in action.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're actually defining the variables? They're commented out in your code...

assuming they are being defined correctly, it's possible they're not of the type you expected - eg sw may be present and populated ut may not have a `lat()` property - perhaps `latitude()`?

Try examining the sw object in a debugger after the bounds change (the firebug addon in firefox is very good for this)

**Edit as your code ahs been changed:**

You're calling the server-side function before the bounds changed function has been called...

Try this:

```
var sw, nw, Searchbounds;

function myFunc(){

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
        Searchbounds = map.getBounds();
        sw = Searchbounds.getSouthWest();
        ne = Searchbounds.getNorthEast();

        //Moved inside the event handler
        CallServerSideWebService(sw.lat(), ne.lng(), ne.lat(), ne.lng());

    });

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay.  I need the sw & ne variable to be accessible outside the event scope.  Your updated code will call the function 'CallServerSideWebService' every time the map bounds have changed.  In simple terms, I need to populate the sw & ne without the use of an event.

Comment: Ok, understood - but in that case, you need to provide default values somehow. In other words, what is in them _before_ the first bounds change?

Comment: The value is only updated when the event fires.  The value before the event is a default value, this is updated during the even, but then goes back to the default value after the event.  In the previous version of google maps (v2), you could simply get the map bounds by:

Searchbounds = map.getBounds();

Without the use of an event.

Comment: odd - it does sound like a scoping issue ie it's setting a local not the global but I've not come acros this behaviour before - what is the value of the variables inside the event listener _before_ they're set? ie can you read the globals? There may be something a little funky happening with regards to XSS protections or similar - ie the google event code is coming from a different domain so can't access your DOM. Does this happen in all browsers? If not, which ones?

Comment: @user547043 You speak of a default value, but I don't see you set that default value anywhere.